# File creation always adds blank line at the end in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am running the following Groovy method to create a text file.

```
def createFile(String path, String fileName)
    {
        new File("$path/$fileName").delete()

        def txtFileInfo = []
        String a = "2014111620141117COMPANYX"
        String b = "2104808660"
        String c = "2104808662"
        String d = "00000002"

        txtFileInfo << a.trim()
        txtFileInfo << b.trim()
        txtFileInfo << c.trim()
        txtFileInfo << d.trim()

        File file = new File("$path/$fileName")

        txtFileInfo.each {
            file << ("${it.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "")}\n")
        }
}
```

The issue is it always adds a blank line at the end of the file. (I.e., after `00000002` in the above example there is a blank line below that in the created file.)

How can I get rid of that blank line? What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending a newline character to the end.  You have that hardcoded in your example.

You could replace this:

```
File file = new File("$path/$fileName")

txtFileInfo.each {
    file << ("${it.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "")}\n")
}
```

With something like this...

```
File file = new File("$path/$fileName")

file << txtFileInfo.join('\n')
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thax. Working perfectly.